# Как отправить json по http протоколу без потери данных

Tags: php, json, http, elasticsearch

отправляю json в php через CURL

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

где `$post` это `json_decode(file_get_contents($mapping_conf));`

$mapping_conf - это json файл

славливаю ошибку

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

также пробовал использовать `json_decode(file_get_contents($mapping_conf));` с вторым аргументом true(чтобы переводил в массив)

от сервера прилетает ошибка `{"error":"Content-Type header [multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------6958761ae20651ff] is not supported","status":406}`
 Пробовал в $post кидать строку json обработанную `urlencode()` и также без нее - с сервера прилетает сообщение `{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}`

преобразовывать json в массив и отправлять массив постом не прокатит, потому как искажаются данные, к примеру {"a":{}} переделается в ["a":[]], на что сервер принимающий ругнется, мол мне нужен тип пустой объект, а ты мне кидаешь пустой массив

Вопрос к знатокам - как надо закодировать json текст, чтобы его можно было запихнуть в POST запрос.

Comment: `$post = file_get_contents($mapping_conf);`
curl_setopt не умеет в классы. Следует уточнить какой формат в файле и что ожидает сервер получающий запрос

Comment: А может, совершенно случайно, принимающий сервер умеет понимать `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: Вам не нужен json_decode. Отправляйте json, как есть, строкой

Answer (score 0):

Всем кто захочет кидать json методом POST - кидайте его как есть - строкой.
Только добавьте два HTTP заголовка:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post))
);
```

где `$post` это json строка

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

Убедитесь прежде [что вы кидаете json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041741/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-is-json-in-php)